# download não é realizado via outputStream

Tags: java, spring-mvc, input-output, inputstream

Estou tentando realizar o download de um arquivo .CSV que tenho salvo.
Entretanto o download não aparece pra mim quando eu clico no botão e não aparece nenhum código de erro.

Como posso testar para ver até que ponto esta sendo realizado o procedimento?

Segue o código:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/gerarCsv/" })
    @ResponseBody
    public void gerarCsv(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @RequestParam(value = "inicio", required = true) String inicio,
            @RequestParam(value = "fim", required = true) String fim) {
        try {

            Date dataInicio = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(inicio);
            Date dataFim = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(fim);

            List<RevogacaoConsolidado> revogacaoConsolidado = revogacao.consultarRevogacaoconsolidado(dataInicio,
                    dataFim);

            File arquivo = new File(context.getRealPath("WEB-INF/classes/statics/downloads/revogacao.csv"));

            logger.info("[Recurso:/admin/revogacao/revogacaoPorDataCSV, sessao:" + request.getSession().getId()
                    + ", usuario:" + request.getUserPrincipal().getName() + "]" + "[Caminho ]" + arquivo);

            // Cria arquivo caso não exista.
            if (!arquivo.exists()) {
                arquivo.createNewFile();
            }

            /*
             * Escreve o arquivo e guarda dentro do caminho desejado objeto arquivo
             */
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(arquivo);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            bw.write("Data" + ";" + "Login" + ";" + "Nome" + ";" + "Sucesso" + ";" + "Erro" + ";" + "Não Cadastrado"
                    + ";" + "Já removido" + ";" + "Total" + ";" + "Porcentagem de Erro %");

            for (RevogacaoConsolidado revog : revogacaoConsolidado) {
                bw.newLine();
                bw.write(revog.getData_processo() + ";" + revog.getLogin() + ";" + revog.getNome() + ";"
                        + revog.getSucesso() + ";" + revog.getErro() + ";" + revog.getNao_cadastrado() + ";"
                        + revog.getJa_removido() + ";" + revog.getTotal() + ";" + revog.getPorcentagem_erro());

            }

            bw.close();
            fw.close();

            /*
             * realiza o download do conteudo.
             */
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=revogacao.csv");
            response.setContentLengthLong((int) arquivo.length());

            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(arquivo);
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            try {

                byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
                int lidos = -1;
                while ((lidos = fileIn.read(outputByte)) != -1) {
                    out.write(outputByte, 0, lidos);
                }
                fileIn.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();

                System.out.println("Download de arquivo");
                logger.info("[Recurso:/admin/revogacao/revogacaoPorDataCSV, sessao:" + request.getSession().getId()
                        + ", usuario:" + request.getUserPrincipal().getName() + "]"
                        + "[Verificação de Revogações por data de processado CSV ] [download de arquivo Realizado]");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            logger.info("[Recurso:/admin/revogacao/revogacaoPorDataCSV, sessao:" + request.getSession().getId()
                    + ", usuario:" + request.getUserPrincipal().getName() + "]"
                    + "[Verificação de Revogações por data de processado CSV ]");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("[Recurso:/admin/revogacao/revogacaoPorDataCSV, sessao:" + request.getSession().getId()
                    + ", usuario:" + request.getUserPrincipal().getName() + "]"
                    + "[Verificação de Revogações por data de processado] error: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Obs: Verificando o console do chrome, na aba de Network, vejo que a requisição foi feita e o método chamado com sucesso, foi gerado até um response com os dados gerados. Quando vejo no Timing vejo que houve um tempo para o content Download. Não deveria estar sendo realizado o download do arquivo?

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que você necessite de utilizar o `write()` para realizar a baixa do seu arquivo no navegador, com o objeto `HttpServletResponse`:

```java
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=seu_arquivo");
response.getOutputStream().write();
response.getOutputStream().flush();
response.getOutputStream().close();
```

Comment: No caso, o meu Write esta dentro do While, se observar  
while ((lidos = fileIn.read(outputByte)) != -1) {
                    out.write(outputByte, 0, lidos);
                }

Comment: Mas você precisa escrever no response pra realizar a baixa do arquivo pelo navegador. O `OutputStream` que eu me refiro é o `getOutputStream()` do `HttpServletResponse response`

Comment: Entendo, porem estou fazendo esse procedimento só que separadamente. no caso meu objeto OUT corresponde ao response.getOutputStream() e dentro do While é onde eu utilizo o Write()

Comment: apenas como uma adição. Quando verifico o Response dentro de Network -> minha função -> Response. Vejo que os dados que ele buscou estão ali, invés de ter feito o download do arquivo.